# Getting JQuery from given HTML text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a question while I parse html using JQuery.

Let me have a simple example for my question.
As you might definitely know, when I need to parse ...

```
<li class="info"> hello </li>
```

I get text by

```
$(".info").text()
```

my question is.. for given full html and token of text  ,can I find query string ?

in case of above example, what I want to get is.

```
var queryStr = findQuery(html,"hello")  // queryStr = '.info'
```

I know there might be more than one result and there would be various type of expression according to DOM hierarchy.

So.. generally... If some text (in this example, 'hello' ) is unique in the whole HTML, I might guess there must be a unique and shortest 'query' string which satisfies $(query).text() = "hello"

My question is.. If my guess is valid, How can I get unique (and if possible, shortest ) query string for each given unique text.

any hint will be appreciated, and thx for your help guys!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you want to do with the selector?

Comment: Do you want the class name based on the text "hello" ?

Answer (score 0):

I create a little function that may help you:

```
function findQuery(str) {
    $("body").children().each(function() {
       if ( $.trim($(this).text()) == $.trim(str) ) {      
        alert("." + $(this).attr("class"))
    } 
    });
}
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbwmh8ey/)

Comment: thx for the tip. I'd like to find general method which will be able to get result even when the text i need to parse is in comlex DOM hierarchy like 
`<li id="test"> noise text <div> ... <br>"hello" </br> ... <div> `

Comment: Ah ok, and post your anwser if you will find the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're actually trying to achieve, but, based on your specific question, you could do the following.

```
var queryStr = findQuery($('<li class="info"> hello </li>'), "hello");  // queryStr = '.info'
// OR
var queryStr = findQuery('<li class="info"> hello </li>', "hello");  // queryStr = '.info' 

alert (queryStr); // returns a string of class names without the DOT. You may add DOT(s) if need be.

function findQuery(html, str) {

    var $html = html instanceof jQuery && html || $(html);
    var content = $html.text();
    if ( content.match( new RegExp(str, "gi") ) ) {
        return $html.attr("class");
    }
    return "no matching string found!";
}
```

Comment: thx for your tip. but I would like to find more general and regex averse way. if possible... thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this demo helps you!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var test = $("li:contains('hello')").attr('class');
  alert(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="info">hello</li>
</ul>
```

Have used the jQuery attribute ":contains".

Comment: thx for the tip! . I 'd like to find more general way , thx again~